# Why are these 2 JavaScript arrays displaying differently in console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm relatively new to web development, so this is probably a simple misunderstanding. I'm using an AJAX request to gather a list of used values within a specific range and then comparing it to a generated list of all possible values within that range to find the unused values.

I've tried using Lodash's _.difference() and the JavaScript Array filter() method, but they return the same results -- all values within the generated range -- which is leading me to believe it's related to the differing structures of the 2 arrays. These methods work when I create a test array like var used = ["0000000030000", "0000000030001"].

This is what the array's look like in the console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErwFC.jpg

The first array shows as [] until expanded; whereas, the other one shows the length of the array and values within?

```
// Will be set dynamically by subdepartment choice, used for testing at the moment.
var startRange = 30000;
var endRange = 39999;

// Pads the startRange and endRange to 13 digits with 0's for the AJAX request.
var startUPC = pad(startRange, 13);
var endUPC = pad(endRange, 13);

// AJAX request function to get all used UPC's within in range of numbers.
function GetNewPLU(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/GetNewPLU",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'startUPC': startUPC, 'endUPC': endUPC },
        success: callback,
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(`Error ${error}`)
        }
    });
}

function SetNewPLU() {

    // Executes GetNewPLU AJAX request function
    var used = [];
    GetNewPLU(function (data) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < data.data.length; $i++) {
            used.push( data.data[$i].OBJ_TAB.F01 );
        }
    });

    var range = [];
    // Generates array of all numbers between range.
    for ($i = startRange; $i < endRange; $i++) {
            range.push( '00000000' + $i );
    };

    //var unused = used.filter(function (n) { return !this.has(n), new Set(data) });
    var unused = _.difference(range.toString(), used);

    console.log(used);
    console.log(range);
    console.log(unused);
}

SetNewPLU();
```

Comment: `used` is filled by the `GetNewPLU` callback and still empty when comparing `_.difference(range.toString(), used)` and logging `console.log(used);`. Have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and/or the [MDN Using Promises guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: I've checked out that first link before, which is where I got the idea to try and use call backs. I just thought maybe I was generating the array incorrectly, but I tested with async: false and it works, so I guess I'll have to look into promises. I was hoping it'd be as simple as implementing calls backs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason all values are returned is simply due to the fact that `used` is still empty at the time of checking the difference. Moving the logic into the callback should resolve this issue.

```
function SetNewPLU() {
    GetNewPLU(function (data) {
        var used = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < data.data.length; $i++) {
            used.push( data.data[$i].OBJ_TAB.F01 );
        }

        var range = [];
        for ($i = startRange; $i < endRange; $i++) {
            range.push( '00000000' + $i );
        };

        var unused = _.difference(range.toString(), used);

        console.log(used);
        console.log(range);
        console.log(unused);
    });
}
```

To avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) you are better of returning promises from your own functions.

```
function GetNewPLU() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "api/GetNewPLU",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'startUPC': startUPC, 'endUPC': endUPC },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(`Error ${error}`);
        }
    });
}

function SetNewPLU() {
    return GetNewPLU().then(function (data) {
        var used = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < data.data.length; $i++) {
            used.push( data.data[$i].OBJ_TAB.F01 );
        }

        var range = [];
        for ($i = startRange; $i < endRange; $i++) {
            range.push( '00000000' + $i );
        };

        var unused = _.difference(range.toString(), used);

        console.log(used);
        console.log(range);
        console.log(unused);
    });
}
```

You could also use the ES6 syntax of `async`/`await`, to reduce the indention of the `SetNewPLU` function. Keep in mind that marking a function as `async` will result in a return value that is always a promise.

```
async function SetNewPLU() {
    var data = await GetNewPLU();

    var used = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < data.data.length; $i++) {
        used.push( data.data[$i].OBJ_TAB.F01 );
    }

    var range = [];
    for ($i = startRange; $i < endRange; $i++) {
        range.push( '00000000' + $i );
    };

    var unused = _.difference(range.toString(), used);

    console.log(used);
    console.log(range);
    console.log(unused);
}
```

> **Note:** The return value of `$.ajax` is an `jqXHR` object, that implements behaviour of a (jQuery) promise object. This object is *thenable*, meaning that the object implements the `then` method, accepting two callbacks. The first one for the success scenario and the second for failure. For this reason it should work when using `await` on the jQuery object. If this for some reason doesn't work, try to wrap the return value of the AJAX call in `GetNewPLU` into `Promise.resolve` before returning. This should convert the jQuery promise to a native JavaScript promise.
>
> - [`$.ajax` return value](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)
> - [`Promise.resolve` (thenable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

For more information about promises and `async`/`await` have a look at the following pages:

- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Async Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (for more example usage)